# Webview In Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, ionic-webview

I have my one blog which i want to convert into ionic app.
I use `InAppBrowser` plugin but the problem is when i press the back button it will come to my default ionic `home` page.

i follow the below steps :

`ionic start myblog`

`ionic platform add android`

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

`npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser`

and then added `provider` in `app.module` and in `home.ts` write the following.

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }


...


const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/','_self','location=no');
browser.show();
```

Also `location=no` is not working.
Like android ionic provide the `webview` ?? 
can anyone help me out ?
any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5):

Simple and sort solution from the [my github repo](https://github.com/KishanIos007/ionic-3-webview)

in `home.html`

```
<iframe  height="100%" width="100%" [src]="urlpaste()"></iframe>
```

and in `home.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  url: any;
  constructor(private sanitize: DomSanitizer) {}
  urlpaste(){
    this.url = "https://hackerrankgeek.wordpress.com/";
    return this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In simpleway without installing any plugin u can use  tag inside which define url of your's blog.
e.g In home.ts :

```
    import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    url: any;
    constructor(private sanitize: DomSanitizer){
    this.url = sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("YOUR_URL");
    }
```

and in `home.html` :

```
<iframe  height="100%" width="100%" [src]="url" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

Try this.

Comment: telling that url is not safe

Comment: can u use DOMSanititizer?

Comment: yup i use as u said