# Ionic 2: InAppBrowser Geolocation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am using [InAppBrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) plugin to open a specific website URL which uses current geo-location to give results. On normal mobile browser like chrome or FireFox, website asks to enable location but on InAppBrowser plugin it won't and therefore, I think, I can't get results according to user location. Is there are any other ways to open a website URL and get results according to current user location.

webiste example like: https://www.foodpanda.pk/

I've also tried to make an iframe and open URL like in this post

> [Webview In Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299642/webview-in-ionic-3)

```
let url = "https://www.foodpanda.pk/";
let target = "_self";
let options = "location=yes,zoom=no";
alert("starting in-app-browser");
const browser = this.iab.create(url, target, options);

browser.on('exit').subscribe(event => {
    alert("Browser exiting");
    this.platform.exitApp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, my application don't have location permissions, so in order to ask user to grant my application permission, I used this plugin [Location Accuracy](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy/). After that websites on in-app-browsers are able to get results according to user current location.